# Incorrect results on NULL value

Tags: trigger

My trigger is very simple and but behavior of NULL condition check produce opposite results. 
The test data doesn't have a value for Parent_company_ID__c. Debug log also gives NULL as the Parent_company_ID__c. But the If else condition works other way around.
Can anyone help?
my test code

```
trigger PopulateLLNonAcctTestTemp on Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c (after update) {

    List<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c> triggeredRecords = new List<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c>();
    List<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c> affectedRecords = new List<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c>();    

    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        triggeredRecords = trigger.new;
    }
    if(trigger.isDelete){
        triggeredRecords = trigger.old;
    }

    System.debug('triggeredFCCRec '+ triggeredRecords);

    Set<Id> affectedFCCIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> affectedAccounts = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> affectedPareantAccount = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Date> affectedRptYr = new Set<Date>();

    //if fcc has updated LLN
    if(triggeredRecords.size()>0){ //when credit is reported or funded months changed to trigger
        for (Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c item: triggeredRecords) {
            if(item.LLN_Pre_assessment_Uploaded_No__c >= 0 || item.LLN_Pre_assessment_Comp_Literacy_No__c >= 0 ||item.LLN_Pre_assessment_Comp_Numeracy_No__c >= 0 )
            {
                affectedRecords.add(item);
                affectedFCCIds.add(item.id);
                affectedAccounts.add(item.Company_ID__c);
                affectedPareantAccount.add(item.Parent_Company_ID__c);
                affectedRptYr.add(item.Reporting_Year__c);
            }
        }
    }
    System.debug('affected TAFAID '+ affectedFCCIds);
    System.debug('affected account '+ affectedAccounts);
    System.debug('affected parent '+ affectedPareantAccount);
    System.debug('affected Year '+ affectedRptYr);
    System.debug('affected Records '+ affectedRecords);

    if(affectedPareantAccount != NULL){
       system.debug('WITH_PARENT ' + affectedPareantAccount);
   }   
    ELSE{
        system.debug('WITH_NO_PARENT ');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`null` and a `Set` of size 0 are not the same thing, and they are also not the same as a `Set` which contains a `null` value.

```
affectedPareantAccount.add(item.Parent_Company_ID__c);
```

The set is clearly not `null`, because if it were, you would get a `NullPointerException` here. If you are working with records that do not have a `Parent_Company_ID__c`, you need to check whether or not that field is `null` before you add it to your Set.

Your condition should be written against `affectedPareantAccount.size() > 0` or `affectedPareantAccount.isEmpty()`, as you prefer. That issue is separate from whether or not you add `null` elements to the Set.

Comment: AffectedParentAccount is defines as Set<Id> affectedPareantAccount = new Set<Id>(); I tried with affectedParentAccount.isEmpty() method as well. but it produces same result.

Comment: Well, if you call `isEmpty()`, you need to invert the result with `!` to make it fit your current if-else logic.

Comment: I used isEmpty method as well but same result either with or without parent account as08:41:07.121 (209863635)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|triggeredFCCRec (Funding_Cycles_Contacts__1---------
|USER_DEBUG|[33]|DEBUG|affected TAFAID {a1p0M00000035TsQAI}
|USER_DEBUG|[34]|DEBUG|affected account {00130000010vWo6AAE}
USER_DEBUG|[35]|DEBUG|affected parent {null}
|USER_DEBUG|[36]|DEBUG|affected Year {2017-01-01 00:00:00}
|USER_DEBUG|[37]|DEBUG|affected Records (--------)
|USER_DEBUG|[43]|DEBUG|WITH_PARENT {null}

Comment: That is not telling you the Set is `null`. It is telling you the Set contains one value and that value is `null`. In other words, `item.Parent_Company_ID__c` was `null`.

Comment: Yes, then why it is not working with NULL check in IF condition?

Comment: I managed to work around using a formula. But still i can't understand why it behaves that way as it clearly shown as NULL on debug

Comment: The Set variable itself being `null` is not the same as the Set, which is not `null`, containing a `null` value. Your `if` condition is only checking whether the `Set` itself is `null`, which is never true because you initialize it

Answer (score 0):

The `if-else` condition should check like this considering the size as you have already initialized that during declaration:

```
if(affectedPareantAccount.size()>0){
       system.debug('WITH_PARENT ' + affectedPareantAccount);
   }   
    ELSE{
        system.debug('WITH_NO_PARENT ');
    }
```